# ¿Como solucionar el problema de tools.jar al compilar con Maven con java 11?

Tags: maven, java-11

Estoy intentando compilar con Maven utilizando Java 11 pero me da un error, busca el tools.jar que este si estaba disponible en Java 8 pero en el 11 ya no existe.

Paso captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedo solucionar el plugin del org.codehaus.mojo añadiendolo en el pom del proyecto, sin embargo el del tools no sé como solucionarlo. He probado introducirlo en el pom la dependencia que pide, copiandolo de un jdk8 y pegandolo en el 11, decirle en el pom la ruta al del jdk 8 y nada me funciona.

La versión de Maven es la 3.6.3 y de JDK es la 11.0.8 la de oracle no la openjdk, la cual tambien he probado y me da el mismo fallo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿De dónde viene la dependencia? ¿Está en tu pom o es una dependencia transitiva?

Comment: Por lo que he podido entender mirando la jerarquía del pom, es transitiva

Comment: Sobre esto hay malas noticias porque el proyecto tiene unos 3 años abandonado https://github.com/mojohaus/aspectj-maven-plugin , por lo que el soporte oficial esta hasta JDK8 si quieres soporte para java 11 tendrás que descargar el proyecto y actualizar la librería `aspectjrt` subir la versión del proyecto y recompilar con java 11, después cambiar a esta nueva versión.

Answer (score 0):

Investigando a tu pregunta he encontrado un usuario de la comunidad que ha realizado un `Fork` de proyecto para realizar la compatibilidad con java 11, debes actualizar el proyecto donde necesites esta librería.

[Proyecto Git](https://github.com/nickwongdev/aspectj-maven-plugin)

[Libreria Mave](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.nickwongdev/aspectj-maven-plugin/1.12.6/maven-plugin)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.nickwongdev</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.12.6</version>
  <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
```